# How to stop iSCSI server?

Tags: iscsi, rhel7

Is it possible to stop listening on iSCSI server port 3260 without deleting the portal from the configuration? I tried to stop all services I know, but it's still running.

```
[root@okvmh1 ~]# systemctl stop iscsid
[root@okvmh1 ~]# systemctl stop iscsi
[root@okvmh1 ~]# systemctl stop target
[root@okvmh1 ~]# netstat -tln | grep 3260
tcp6       0      0 :::3260                 :::*                    LISTEN
[root@okvmh1 ~]# iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal localhost
[::1]:3260,1 iqn.2014-08.com.example:t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way to stop the kernel based iscsi_target_mod I've found seems to be to reboot.